# A bag with 3 black balls and 33 white balls, find expected number of pulls

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value

So I stumbled upon this question:
I got a bag with 36 balls: 3 black and 33 white. I need to calculate the expected amount of pulls **without putting the pulled ball back into the bag** before I get:

(a) 1 black ball

(b) all 3 black balls

So, for (a): I used straight definition of expected value, which says, that the result is equal to:
$1*\frac{3}{36} + 2 * \frac{33}{36}*\frac{3}{35} + 3 * \frac{33}{36}*\frac{32}{35}*\frac{3}{34} + ...$

But I couldn't come up with a closed form for this so I've left it at that, for now, trying to find a better way.

For (b) I tried the same approach but for probabilities I tried to use combinatorics. For example, the total amount of ways to take 3 balls out of 36 is (36 choose 3) = 7140.

Now then, there is only 1 setup for a success with 3 attempts aka 1st ball, 2nd ball and 3rd ball

For 4 attempts, last attempt is locked for the 3rd ball and then I got 3 choose 2 ways = 3 ways to distribute 2 remaining balls between first 3 attempts

For 5 attempts, same logic, but now I got 4 choose 2 ways = 6 ways to distribute 2 remaining balls between first 4 attempts.

And so on and on

Then I calculate the probability by dividing the number of ways by 7140 and then calculate the expectation. I got 27.75 there, with Excel.

But here is the problem. I decided to randomly simulate this process using Python with 10000000 runs and my answers simply don't match the simulation outcome, which is 8 for 1 ball and 24 for 3 balls. I can only imagine that my math is wrong, so ... I seek help.

Comment: A symmetry argument (counting from the other end) suggests that the answers to (1) and (2) should add up to $3+33+1=37$

Comment: Thank you for the comment, sir. Unfortunately I'm not sure how to utilize Your hint.

Comment: I am saying that your simulation results look implausible

Comment: Have you considered this being a binomial distribution?

Comment: My $3+33+1=37$ result is based on the expected number of draws without replacement to get the first or last black ball.  If you want the number of draws "before" this happens (i.e. one less in each case) then you would get $3+33-1=35$

Comment: @Henry Damn, you are indeed correct. Thank you for pointing this out, it was driving me nuts, I tell you. Now the 1 ball simulation shows approximately 9 attempts and approximately 27 for 3 balls, but this adds up to 36 ... ugh, is there still something wrong then? I'll be honest, your symmetry argument seems very arcane to me, as in, I dont understand, why this argument suggest your equation.

Comment: @SupremePickle not sure if I can use it here since I can't put the balls back. Maybe I'm not understanding it well enough then?

Comment: My simulations suggest $9.25$ and $27.75$

Comment: @Henry Ok, I see now. Fixed another mistake (was using random.randrange instead of random.randint), and yep, now it matches your numbers. Thank you for your input. The question is resolved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let the number of white balls before the first black ball, between the first and second black balls, between the second and third black ball, and after the last black ball be denoted by $x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4}$ respectively.

$$
x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}+x_{4}=33
$$

Because of symmetry, we get the following identity for expectation of $x_{i}$:

$$
\begin{align}
E(x_{1})=E(x_{2})=E(x_{3})=E(x_{4})&=\frac{1}{4}E(x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}+x_{4})\\
\\
&=\frac{33}{4}
\end{align}
$$

1. The expected number of draw for the first black ball is $E(x_{1})+1=\frac{37}{4}$
2. The expected number of draws for the last black ball is $E(x_{1})+E(x_{2})+E(x_{3})+3=\frac{111}{4}$

Comment: Can you say how that "symmetry" argument works? It seems not obvious to me.

Comment: Amazing. I clearly need to try look at such questions from many different angles. Thank you for the solution.

Comment: @Ingix $P(X_{i}=x_{i})=\frac{\binom{33-x_{i}+2}{2}}{\binom{33+3}{3}}$

Comment: @Ingix I think I butchered that notation haha but I hope you get my point

Comment: Intuitively I can see why  $E(x_1) = E(x_4)$ by symmetry, and also why $E(x_2) = E(x_3)$. But I can't see why $E(x_1) = E(x_2)$. Is it obvious to you? Perhaps my intuition about symmetry doesn't extend to this for some reason!

Comment: Ok I see it now - for any values $a$ and $b$ of $x_1$ and $x_2$, we can think of the probability as conditional on the second black ball being in position $a + b + 2$. We can then see by symmetry that $P(x_1 = a \cap x_2 = b) = P(x_1 = b \cap x_2 = a)$.

Comment: @alcana there are as many possible non negative integer solutions for $x_{1}+x_{3}+x_{4}=33-a$ as for $x_{2}+x_{3}+x_{4}=33-a$ or for any sum of three $x_{i}$s